# QML - Using ListView with dynamically generated ListElement

Tags: qt, qml

I have this QML with the ListView:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import smah.light 1.0
import smah.zone 1.0

Page {

    id: page
    property var lights: ({})
    property var lightNames: ([])
    title: "Device control"

    ListView {
        id: lightList
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: listModel
        delegate:
            Rectangle{
            width: lightList.width
            height: lightList.height / 8
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        dynamicRoles: true
        Component.onCompleted: {
            listModel.clear()
            for (var i=0; i<lights.length; i++) {
                var component = Qt.createComponent("LightControls.qml",listModel)
                listModel.append(component.createObject(lightList, {light_name: lights[i].getName }))
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The LightControls.qml is:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import smah.light 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    property int light_type: 0
    property int light_id: 0
    property var light_name: "_DEF"
    width: parent.width
    height: 50
    color: "#040000"

    Text {
        id: txtName
        color: "#fefdfd"
        text: qsTr(light_name)
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 15
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 8
        font.pixelSize: 20
    }

    Slider {
        id: slider
        x: 179
        y: 10
        width: 302
        height: 22
        value: 0.5
    }

    Text {
        id: txtValue
        x: 517
        width: 45
        height: 15
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: qsTr("Text")
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 8
        font.pixelSize: 20
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 694
        y: 10
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }
}
```

I want a clean scrollable list with each of these items generated shown in it. I've looked at using a Repeater instead of the list, but I'll have more elements in the list than are desired on the screen. When running the program, everything is garbled into a single incoherent mess:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few larger issues with your code:

1. You're trying to add a visual item to a `ListModel`, which expects `ListElement` objects. You can use [`append()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#append-method) to add rows to a `ListModel`.
2. Your root delegate item is a `Rectangle`, which doesn't manage the layout of its children. Use a `RowLayout` or `Row` instead.
3. Your delegate should be `delegate: LightControls {}`.

Comment: Still no luck..

For #1 Isn't 
`listModel.append(component.createObject(lightList, {light_name: lights[i].getName }))` accomplishing this(adding rows to the model with this object?

I've done #2 and 3, but it's still jumbled on top - although changing the root delegate to a `Row` seems to have organized the items slightly better in the jumble

Comment: In your example you're creating a `Rectangle` component (LightControls.qml) and trying to append it to a `ListModel`, which will never work. Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#modifying-list-models.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. LightControls.qml is now 
`Row { .. ` instead of `Rectangle {.. `

Comment: Same thing; `Row` is a visual type. `ListModel` only supports `ListElement` or JS objects (as shown in the docs). When I say "add rows to `ListModel`", I mean model rows, which is a separate concept to the `Row` item. Have you read the documentation I linked to in my answer and the previous comment? It explains how to do what you need.